# C#, convert string to DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset, tryparse

I am trying to convert a string into DateTimeOffset. here is an example of my string `2017/010/23:51:50` 2017 represents year 010 represent day of the year and 23:51:50 is time.
I am trying in below way but it returns me `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00` always no mater the input is.
My code

```
DateTimeOffset DateTime;
string year = ("2017/010/23:51:50");
DateTimeOffset.TryParse(year, out DateTime);
```

Any suggestion please?

**Update**
For simplicity I did not linger my question. My date time I am getting year (`2017 it could be 2002, 2001` ) from name of a `.txt` file and day and time (`010/23:51:50` some has offset and some content don't) from the content of that `.txt` file. So my input is not always same. hope this clarifies

Comment: When you say *day of the year*, do you mean like from 1 to 365?

Comment: It returned *false*, never ignore that.  Use Parse() instead to keep yourself honest.

Comment: You are correct  @OfirWinegarten

Comment: Why are you using `DateTimeOffset`? The date string doesn't contain offset information. Is it in UTC?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824186/parsing-a-datetimeoffset-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: This is very helpful @GBreen12

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant will keep it in mind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a DateTimeOffset string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824186/parsing-a-datetimeoffset-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @GBreen12 may be my question is not duplicate. For simplicity I did not linger my question. My date time I am getting year (2017) from name of a .txt file and  day and time (010/23:51:50 some has offset and some content dont) from the content of that .txt file. So my input is not always same but format is.

Comment: The easiest way is to subtact the Date property which is midnight.  So DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse("string date").  DateTime offset = myDate - myDate.Date;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First split the string by / and then use the dayOfTheYear value and the year to obtain the year/month/date. Next split the time parameter and use it to obtain TimeSpan and add it to the previously obtained date. Next, simply parse your newly obtained date to DateTimeOffset. This code should work:

```
        string year = ("2017/010/23:51:50");
        var date = year.Split('/');
        var timeSpanVal = date[2].ToString().Split(':').Select(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(timeSpanVal[0], timeSpanVal[1], timeSpanVal[2]);
        DateTime newDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(date[0]), 1, 1).AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(date[1]) - 1)+ts;

        DateTimeOffset.TryParse(newDate.ToString(), out DateTime);
```

Comment: One doesn't need to go through a string to convert from `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset`.  However, you do need to know what offset you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the [date and time formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), I don't think you can parse the format `Year/JulianDay/Time`. What you can do is split the string into parts and then add the days to the year

```
string[] parts = year.Split('/');
DateTime dt = new DateTime(int.Parse(parts[0]), 1, 1); 
dt = dt.AddDays(int.Parse(parts[1]) - 1).Add(TimeSpan.Parse(parts[2]));
```